# Obtaining the euclidean distance from the cosine similarity

Tags: vector-spaces, algorithms, vectors

In an algorithm improvement problem, I was thinking that the **cosine similarity** along with the **euclidean distance** could be obtained in a way that the number of times it needs to calculate a square and a square root is reduced.

The idea was to store in a database a set of vectors as tuples that contains the unit vector components, the magnitude and the square of the magnitude.

$$ \mathbf{V}^n = [\hat{v_1}, \hat{v_2} \dots \hat{v_n}, |V|, |V|^2]$$
So the database will contain the following data.

$$
\mathbf{V}^n_m=
\begin{array}(
  (\hat{v_{11}}, \hat{v_{12}} \dots \hat{v_{1n}}, M_1, S_1)\\
  (\hat{v_{21}}, \hat{v_{22}} \dots \hat{v_{2n}}, M_2, S_2)\\
  \vdots \\
  (\hat{v_{m1}}, \hat{v_{m2}} \dots \hat{v_{mn}}, M_m, S_m)
\end{array}$$

Where

$$ M_m = |V_m| $$
$$ S_m = |V_m|^2$$

In this way, for any two given vectors, I can obtain the **cosine similarity** as the dot product of the corresponding unit vectors:

$$
\cos_\ \theta_{V_1V_2} =  \hat{v_1} \cdot \hat{v_2} = \hat{v_{11}}\hat{v_{21}} + \hat{a_{12}}\hat{b_{22}}+ \dots +\hat{a_{1n}}\hat{b_{2n}} \\ \cos_\ \theta_{V_1V_3} =  \hat{v_1} \cdot \hat{v_3} = \hat{v_{11}}\hat{v_{31}} + \hat{a_{12}}\hat{b_{32}}+ \dots +\hat{a_{1n}}\hat{b_{3n}} \\
\vdots \\
\cos_\ \theta_{V_1V_n} =  \hat{v_1} \cdot \hat{v_n} = \hat{v_{11}}\hat{v_{n1}} + \hat{a_{12}}\hat{b_{n2}}+ \dots +\hat{a_{1n}}\hat{b_{nn}} \\
\vdots
$$

Now, intuitively, I just thought that having the cosine, I could obtain the **euclidean distance** by means of the law of cosines, thus:

$$  \mathbf{d_{V_1V_2}} = \sqrt{S_1+S_2-2M_1M_2\cos\ \theta_{V_1V_2}} \\
\mathbf{d_{V_1V_3}} = \sqrt{S_1+S_3-2M_1M_3\cos\ \theta_{V_1V_3}} \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf{d_{V_1V_n}} = \sqrt{S_1+S_n-2M_1M_n\cos\ \theta_{V_1V_n}} \\
\vdots
$$

In this way, the cost to calculate both metrics between any two given vectors is reduced to a single square root calculation. Now, I said intuitively because I can visualize the law of cosines in a 2-dimension and 3-dimension space but I am not sure about higher dimensions.

Is there a flaw in the reasoning? Is the law of cosines valid for dimensions higher than 3?

Comment: I think those [two](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146221/is-cosine-similarity-identical-to-l2-normalized-euclidean-distance) [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Properties) may be related to your question and thoughts

Comment: If you just take $\mathbf A\cdot \mathbf B$ instead of $|\mathbf{A}||\mathbf{B}|\cos\theta_{AB}$ (which is the same quantity), you would save a lot of square roots (to get $|\mathbf{A}|$ and $|\mathbf{B}|$) and division (to get the unit vector components). Or just get $|\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}|^2$ via inner product to get the entire expression you have under the square root.

Comment: It seems to me your method actually takes _more_ square roots than the standard method (which needs only one root per distance computed).

Comment: Thank you @DavidK, it is true that it may seem that I'm doing more calculations and indeed that's true with only two vectors. But if I have one thousand vectors, the cost of obtaining the unit vector is only one set of operations per vector. Now, when I want to calculate the metrics for any two of the given vectors there's where the real cost comes.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning about cosines is fine; I think there's quite a bit of math in which we actually *define* the angle between two vectors by taking the arc cosine of their inner product.

I think that answers your question; the rest of what follows is essentially a comment and suggestion relative to your proposed method.

Let's see what happens if you store the data this way:
$$
\mathbf{V} =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  (v_{11}, v_{12}, \ldots v_{1n}, S_1)\\
  (v_{21}, v_{22}, \ldots v_{2n}, S_2)\\
  \vdots \\
  (v_{m1}, v_{m2}, \ldots v_{mn}, S_m)
\end{array}
\right),$$
where 
$S_i = \lVert \mathbf V_i\rVert^2 = v_{i1}^2 + v_{i2}^2 + \cdots v_{in}^2$
for each $1 \leq i \leq m.$
Then for any $1 \leq i < j \leq m,$

$$ 
\lVert \mathbf V_i\rVert \lVert \mathbf V_j\rVert \cos \theta_{V_iV_j}
= \mathbf V_i \cdot \mathbf V_j
= v_{i1}v_{j1} + v_{i1}v_{j1} + \cdots + v_{i1}v_{j1}.
$$

Instead of performing $n + 2$ multiplications and $n - 1$ additions to obtain 
$M_1 M_2 \cos \theta_{V_1V_2}$ from $M_1,$ $M_2,$ and the $2n$ components of the unit vectors $\hat {\mathbf V}_1$ and $\hat {\mathbf V}_2,$
you could perform $n$ multiplications and $n - 1$ additions to obtain 
$\lVert \mathbf V_i\rVert \lVert \mathbf V_j\rVert \cos \theta_{V_1V_2}$ from the $2n$ components of the original vectors ${\mathbf V}_1$ and ${\mathbf V}_2.$
Then every time you compute

$$ \mathbf{d_{V_iV_j}} = \sqrt{S_i + S_j - 2 \mathbf V_i \cdot \mathbf V_j} $$

it would cost you $n + 1$ multiplications (including the multiplication by $2$),
$n$ additions, one subtraction, and one square root,
rather than $n + 3$ multiplications,
$n$ additions, one subtraction, and one square root.
Moreover, you save the cost of computing $M_i,$ $M_j,$ and all the $\hat v_{ik}$
and  $\hat v_{jk}$ components in the first place.

Granted, if the number of vectors is much larger than the number of dimensions, the number of operations saved is a small fraction of the total cost of computing all the distances, but the point is that storing vectors in the form
$$ (\hat v_{11}, \hat v_{12}, \ldots \hat v_{1n}, M_1, S_1)$$
rather than
$$(v_{11}, v_{12}, \ldots v_{1n}, S_1)$$
saves you *nothing* (and actually incurs some added cost) for the purpose of this exercise.

That's not to say there isn't some application where precomputing all the values of 
$\lVert \mathbf V_i\rVert$ would lower the cost of computation. I've considered that trick myself from time to time. It just doesn't pay off for this particular application.